Use Multiple sources in an AWS-CodePipeline pipeline for a lambda invoke
I have been trying to implement a functionality on code-pipeline AWS which I have yet been unable to implement.
So, I have my code repositories on Bitbucket for my microservices. On Bitbucket, I have built a pipeline that uploads the jars to respective S3 buckets. I have my application running on AWS.
Now, Upon each successful upload of a jar, there is an event triggered that acts as a source for my code pipeline pipeline. The codepipeline has two stages source stage and a lambda invoke stage.

Let's say I have two services I have to build a pipeline in which these stages have multiple steps which are independent of each other. I am unable to make them independently identifiable. When a B-service event is triggered both A-service-step and b-service-step are executed.
I tried to achieve this using two methods :

user-parameters in the lambda invoke stage but it was of no use because eventually both the steps are triggered on any event.




In the source stage for "Change detection options" - if I use AWS CodePipeline in place of Amazon cloudwatch events there is a variable I can see "PollForSourceChanges" which has the trigger value as A-service-jar if the trigger was from A-service bucket. However, I am unable to use it in the lambda invoke stage. If there is a way to extract that value in the lambda script then I can write the conditional script.


All I am trying to do is to avoid creating multiple pipelines and save the hassle of managing them because there are quite several microservices.

Also, one more conceptual question, which might help me with another approach : is aws-codepipeline made in a way "one environment all services" or "one service all environments"
maybe if 2nd is correct i was doint it wrong all the way

In your Lambda function, access the event data passed to the pipeline. This event data will contain information about which S3 bucket triggered the pipeline.For example, in the Lambda function, you can extract the bucket name and conditionally execute logic here I assume each service has it's own S3 bucket :
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    input_artifact = event['CodePipeline.job']['data']['inputArtifacts'][0]
    bucket_name = input_artifact['location']['s3Location']['bucketName']
    
    
    if "A-service-bucket" in bucket_name:
        print("Triggering A-service deployment...")
        # Add your specific A-service deployment logic here
    
    elif "B-service-bucket" in bucket_name:
        # Logic for B-service
        print("Triggering B-service deployment...")

    
    else:
        print("Unrecognized bucket:", bucket_name)
        raise Exception("Unknown bucket name")
    
    # Notify CodePipeline of a successful invocation
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Lambda function executed successfully')
    }

If you prefer to keep the logic within the CodePipeline itself, you can use CodePipeline variables. The PollForSourceChanges option you're using is a good start, but you'd need to pass that variable to the Lambda function as an environment variable

that would not be possible because


if i have only a single lambda invoke stage, all the source artifacts from previous stage would have to be allowed to the lambda to be able to process them, and since all the source stages gets triggered upon any event this would pass all the respective bucket names in the event parameters. i had tried it out


if i have individual lambda invoke stages for each microservice, same would happen that since all the sources are triggered for any event i cannot conditionally execute the lambda for a particular event.


i have tried both of the ways

problem is that there seems no way possible to make the sources independent in a single pipeline. or atleast i am not able to find it.
The PollForSourceChanges option you're using is a good start, but you'd need to pass that variable to the Lambda function as an environment variable ---- please tell me how, i am unable to extract it
